# why is permission denied for bzr push?

Tags: bash, version-control, permissions, bazaar, chmod

user2 wants to bzr push changes to a directory `/home/user1/project/dev`. user2 has group +rwx permissions on this directory, but not in my home directory `/home/user1/`

This results in the error:

> bzr: ERROR: Permission denied: "h2i9usf1l6ieofpuul87.pack": [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   '/home/user1/.bzr/repository/upload/h2i9usf1l6ieofpuul87.pack'

It is not clear to me why user2 needs permission to my home `/home/user1/.bzr/` when `/home/user1/project/dev` is branch is from `/home/usr1/project/trunk`.

I am relatively new to using VCS and am not sure how I got in this predicament. Is there a way to break the dependency on the `/home/user1/.bzr`, or to create a branch from `/home/user1/project/trunk/` that does not have this dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(provided by user3)
This might be fixed using following commands (group name is `project_dev`):

```
chgrp -R project_dev /home/user1/project/dev
find /home/user1/project/dev -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
```

1. make all files owned by group cheas_dev,
2. add the sticky bit to all folders making it that all files/folders created under it will also be owned by group `project_dev`.

Comment: It's not a sticky bit (1777 or t). It's a setgid bit (2777 or s).

Answer (score 4):

It seems you have shared repository in `/home/user1/` and branch at `/home/user1/project/dev` is using that repository. Therefore it needs access to repository to store new revisions.

How to check: run command `bzr info` and check its output for the definition of that branch. If you will see "Repository tree" or "Repository branch" then that branch definitely using a shared repository. You should see the path to the repository in the output of `bzr info`.

How to fix: instruct bzr to stop using shared repository by executing command `bzr reconfigure --standalone` in the branch at `/home/user1/project/dev`. Check output of `bzr info` again. Now it should be named "Standalone tree" or "Standalone branch". After that user2 should be able to successfully push to that branch.

Comment: thank you for your answer. This makes sense, but it only changed the error to: `ERROR: Permission denied:'/home/user1/project/dev/.bzr/repository/upload/h2i9usf1l6ieofpuul87.pack'bzr: [Errno 13] Permission denied` I have posted an alternative solution, still waiting to hear if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think all parent directories should have o+x permissions.